# How to match all regular expression groups with or without character between them

Tags: c#, regex

Here is my regular expression

```
(".+?")*([^{}\s]+)*({.+?})*
```

Generally matching with this expression work well, but only if there is any character between matched groups. For example this:

```
{1.0 0b1 2006-01-01_12:34:56.789} {1.2345 0b100000 2006-01-01_12:34:56.789}
```

produces two matches:

```
1. {1.0 0b1 2006-01-01_12:34:56.789}
2. {1.2345 0b100000 2006-01-01_12:34:56.789}
```

but this:

```
{1.0 0b1 2006-01-01_12:34:56.789}{1.2345 0b100000 2006-01-01_12:34:56.789}
```

only one containing last match:

```
{1.2345 0b100000 2006-01-01_12:34:56.789}
```

PS. I'm using switch `g` for global match

EDIT: 
I do research in meantime and I must to provide additional data. I pasted whole regular expression which matches also words and strings so asterix after groups is neccecary

EDIT2: Here is example text:

```
COMMAND STATUS {OBJECT1}{OBJECT2} "TEXT" "TEXT"
```

As a result I want this groups:

```
COMMAND
STATUS
{OBJECT1}
{OBJECT2}
"TEXT1"
"TEXT2"
```

Here is my actual C# code:

```
var regex = new Regex("(\".+?\")*([^{}\\s]+)*({.+?})*");
var matches = regex.Matches(responseString);
return matches
   .Cast<Match>()
   .Where(match => match.Success && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(match.Value))
            .Select(match => CommandParameter.Parse(match.Value));
```

Comment: No need for `*`, `\{.*+\}` is enough. What language are you using?

Comment: it's used in C# code

Comment: Please show actual code.

Comment: With the * quantifier on the capture group, you've allowed it to match consecutive bracketed strings in THE SAME GROUP. When this happens, the engine returns only the last match. When there's a character in-between, you're getting multiple matches, so it's not a problem. See http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html#groupnumbers for a good explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra quantifier `*` for `({.+?})` sub-pattern.

You can use this regex:

```
("[^"]*"|{[^}]*}|[^{}\s]+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lZ5uE3/3)

And note how it matches both groups one with space between them and one without any space.

Comment: Yes indeed, but it won't capture other groups. See my last edit. I know I should have provide whole thing at first time. Sorry

Comment: Yes it works! :). Why not use `.*?` instead of `[^}]`?

Comment: Because negation pattern `[^}]` is far more efficient than `.*?`, esp. useful when you have longer input stings to match.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following regex to capture all the `{...}`s:

```
(".+?"|[^{}\s]+|{[^}]+?})
```

See [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/uQ7nJ7/3).

My approach to capture anything inside some single characters is using a negated character class with the same character. Also, since you are matching non-empty texts, you'd better off using `+` quantifier that ensures at least 1 character match.

*EDIT:*

Instead of making each group optional, you should use alternative lists.

Comment: I edited my question and pasted actual whole regular expression. I didn't at the first time, because I have thougth it's not a part of the problem. Sorry

Comment: Please check the updated regex. Note that regex engines get crazy when you only use optional groups in a regular expression.

Comment: Yes it works! :). Why not use `.*?` instead of `[^}]`?

Comment: Well, if you are not using multiline option, but the string has a newline, `[^}]` will match it. It depends on the input. Maybe in your case, it just does not matter much and you can use a dot, too.